# Get two properties at runtime and make combination of those two properties in string (orderby orderdirection)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, widget

I have two properties "orderby" and "orderdirection" in widget.
In runtime I can adjust those properties check snip :
[image]

I want to set these properties in my rest api query.
eg: Query = "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?&"$select=ID,Title,Date&$orderby=**Title desc,Date asc**"

Above values are hardcoded but I want to change those values in runtime. When I want to update just one value "Title desc", its easy but I want to set any number of columns at runtime.

My approach : Spilt the string first **orderby.Split(",")** and then make one string with both combination of "**orderby orderdirection,orderby orderdirection,orderby orderdirection**".

I just wanted to check if any other approach I can try here. Please suggest your suggestion here. Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a solution :

```js
    var orderby = "Title,Date,Other";
    var orderdirection = "desc,asc,asc";
    
    var ar0 = orderby.split(",");
    var ar1 = orderdirection.split(",");
    var res=[];
    for(let i = 0; i < ar0.length; i++){
        res.push(ar0[i] + ' ' + ar1[i]);
    }
    
    var result = res.join(",");
    console.log(result);
```